# regex cut css and js links from html

Tags: java, regex

I need to cut all css and js links from page, now Im using that regex:

```
([^ ()]*\.(?:css|js)\b)
```

Its works fine but its also cuts some links like:

```
href="stylesheets/{asfas}asf{,,.,sfasfas]F{asfas]fAS/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css
```

What I need to add to my regex to exclude that invalid links. I think I need exclude chars like '{},.' from regex matcher?

Im using JAVA Pattern/Macther to compile my regex.

Pls dont suggest me usage of html parsers(like Jsoup and etc).

**update1**:[image]

Comment: it's work fine. `find()` and `group()` give me an expected result

Comment: mm, I want to ignore links like 'href="stylesheets/{asfas}asf{,,.,sfasfas]F{asfas]fAS/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css', but now I grab them, pls see my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with regex like this:

```
(?<==)([^ (){},]*?\.(?:css|js)\b)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vC7nI7/5)

or:

```
(?<=\s)([^ (){},]*?\.(?:css|js)\b)
```

if you want also to grab href/src.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack I updated answer, what you think about new one?